# Allocating users into groups on condition

Tags: excel, sorting, grouping, datasheet

I have this datasheet with 5 columns:

[image]

```
 1. user ID
 2. date
 3. status
 4. doctor ID
 5. visit ID
```

I need to divide users (by their ID) into three groups:

1. Users who booked a visit to a doctor by themselves (`status =
   'booked-user'`) and after that doctor booked the visit for them
   (status = 'booked-doctor')
2. Users who were booked by doctor first (`status = 'booked-doctor'`) and
   after that they have booked visit by themselves (`status =
   'booked-user'`)
3. All others

Is there some way to use advanced filter to include two conditions?
Any ideas?

This is the way I see the output:

[image]

Groups could be also exported to separate sheets.

Comment: Sounds like you can just filter the Status Column `A - Z` and it will group them for you unless you are trying to separate them by sheet

Comment: I have to include the first and second status for every user, so it is more complexed. As you can see on the screen, every user had a few appointments, eg. CELL A2 (User ID 393382011001) -> first status is booked-user, second status is booked-doctor, so this User should go to group 1)

Comment: Is this input or output? If it is input, provide a photo of what the output of your data shown will look like plz!

Comment: Ok, I have added a screen of output, that I'd like to get. Groups could also be separate Excel sheets.